# Qt, using OpenGL, QGLWidget is private

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm quite new to Qt. I wanted to create a simple application where there's triangle generated using OpenGL and three push buttons changing that triangle colour. Unfortunately I get an error:

> E:\Programy\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtOpenGL\qgl.h:457: error: 'QGLWidget::QGLWidget(const QGLWidget&)' is private
>        Q_DISABLE_COPY(QGLWidget)

I don't know what to do. Here's my code:

MainWindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QVBoxLayout *layout;

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


private:
    QPushButton *redButton;
    QPushButton *greenButton;
    QPushButton *blueButton;

public slots:
    void redSlot(Widget w);
    void greenSlot(Widget w);
    void blueSlot(Widget w);

};
```

Slots in MainWindow.cpp look like this:

```
void MainWindow::redSlot(Widget w)
{
    w.setColor(red);
}
```

Widget.h

```
class Widget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;
    QSize sizeHint() const;

    enum color c;

    void setColor(enum color color1);

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);

};
```

enum color is just an enum declared ina another header file

```
enum color
{
    red,
    green,
    blue
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Slots`

```
void redSlot(Widget w);
void greenSlot(Widget w);
void blueSlot(Widget w);
```

all take a Parameter of Type `Widget`. This tries to create a copy of the object when called. Your `Widget` is a subclass of `QGLWidget` which has a private copy constructor and therefore can't be called from a subclassed object.

As you want to change the color of an existing object and not a copy of it you should change the functions to take a pointer of that object:

```
void redSlot(Widget*);
void greenSlot(Widget*);
void blueSlot(Widget*);

void MainWindow::redSlot(Widget* w)
{
    w->setColor(red);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to register pointer via `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( Widget * )`

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I don't think pointers need that, I could e wrong though